# Android studio takes half an hour to start on windows. Any fix?

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I have a fresh install of complete Android Studio and every time I start it, it takes 27 to 34 minutes to launch to a workable state.

My PC Specs:

```
Windows 7 Ultimate
Ram: 4GB
Processor: Intel Core i3
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this? I tried searching everywhere but all I seem to be the only one having this problem as all "slow android" questions and solutions are about emulators and not the actual android studio. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Android studio is a resource sucker and you may be at the low end for your RAM.

Comment: I've Noticed its faster when you use any other Theme than the Dark Theme

Comment: @KristyWelsh All I want to fix is the startup time (30mins!!!), rest it is a bit slow but thats fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

Try eclipse luna

[download eclipse here](https://eclipse.org/downloads/)

and install adt plugin in eclipse luna

[how to install adt](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Comment: Eclipse is no longer supported.

Comment: It is Fully supported.

i develop android apps using eclipse and i don't have any problem.

read this [blog](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Comment: I meant that it is no longer the official IDE. It will recieve no more updates.  If you want to continue using the latest and greatest software ( in which AndroidStudio is far superior and quite enlightening once you learn your way around) then you should migrate.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

Create a file named `gradle.properties` inside:

```
C:\Users\<myusername>\.gradle (Windows)
```

containing this instruction:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

and this one too:

Go to `Preferences` -> `Project settings` -> `Compiler`, type `--offline` in the box.

Comment: Where exactly can I find the ``Preferences`` ?

Comment: I created the ``gradle.properties`` file and now my studio takes 25mins to startup, 5 minute less than what it used it take.